# Getting EOF error which call APNS in golang with developement certificate

Tags: go, apple-push-notifications

**What version of Go are you using?**

> go version go1.13 linux/amd64

**What OS and processor architecture are you using?**

> OS: CentOS-7 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**What did I do?**

> Span 100 threads using goroutine reach thread read data from
>   redis,data is in json which contains key csv_file path.Each csv
>   contains 1000 tokens. Each thread pop data from redis and read csv and
>   spawn 1000 threads, how much tokens that much thread and call APNS
>   push. During the push getting "EOF". 90% calls failed with this error.
>   I have set my OS ulimit is 500000
>   **what did you expect to see?** It should get processed 10M tokens in 1 minute

**What did I see instead?**

> I am getting following error when call APNS sevice with load testing
>   on dev certificate time="2020-02-25T08:54:44-05:00" level=info
>   msg="Push Error:%!(EXTRA *url.Error=Post
>   https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com/3/device/eoQtFQtlL4s:APA91bGrV0HqQH4qbxe
>   ZCJrX-XMHj63: EOF)" 90% calls failed with this error. each thread with
>   1000 tokens publishe taken 2s with EOF error which is extermelly slow.

**Further informations:**
Aim:

> My aim is publish 10M tokens in 1 minute

Where I run the code:

> I am running in golang code in aws EC2 instance in Virginia us-east-1

My question:

> When this error came and how can I fix?

It will be great if I can get help.

Comment: APNS push did you check the underlying behavior of this service. Think it is making connection to an external service. there should be some file descriptor limitation.

Comment: I have increased ulimit to 500000. After that also I am facing this issue. I am using https://github.com/sideshow/apns2